# Delete file with google drive API PHP V3 permission error

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have an issue with google drive PHP API V3 I'm trying to remove a file from the drive using the code below:

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Drive API PHP');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '/root/.credentials/drive-php.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY
)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cgi-fcgi') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents(CREDENTIALS_PATH), true);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents(CREDENTIALS_PATH, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$optParams = array(
    'fields' => 'files(id, createdTime)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) != 0) {
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        $service->files->delete($file['id']);
    }
}
```

All is working I can get the ID of the file but when I try to delete it I get the below error.
Any idea why please?

Thanks

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
       }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Insufficient Permission"
     }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious?

Comment: Do you think if I know how to fix I would have posted this topic?

Comment: There is nothing to fix, you are trying to delete a file which you have "insufficient permissions" for and now you complain that it fails. It should fail, exactly for that reason! Either you simply don't try to delete the file or you first get the permissions to delete the file.

Comment: This file is in my own google drive which I associate with the server where I'm runing from my PHP script as they are suggesting in the documentation. So for me the file should be deleted and I should not get a permission error. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY` cannot be used for deleting files using Drive API. So how about using `Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE` as the scope?

When you modified the scope, please remove the file of `drive-php.json` at `/root/.credentials/`, and run the script again. By this, the access token and refresh token reflected the modified scope can be retrieved.

And then, please confirm whether Drive API is enabled again.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: @oussama kamal Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved.